# Dependency Injection UnitOfWork Pattern In Asp.Net Core

Tags: .net, unit-of-work

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AirlineManagement.Repository.UnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'AirlineManagement.Controllers.StudentsController'.

What is that meaning exactly and how can i solved it??

For more info
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/660

Comment: Where do you make `AirlineContext` available for injection? Also, format your code properly.

Comment: Thank @AluanHaddad for replay can please look at below link there i have full format code please take look you will understand where i make AirlineContext

(https://github.com/MurtuzaTravadi/DotNetCoreRepositoryPattern)

Thank you

Comment: I took a look but the code there is less complete, albeit better formatted, than the code in your GitHub issue. It is pretty all over the place. Follow @RickvandenBosch's advice, he seems to know what he is talking about.

Comment: Looks like your GitHub issue is improving slightly, but you need to add C# after the 3 backticks in order to get the syntax to highlight. \`\`\`c#(linebreak)(code) (linebreak)```

Comment: Thank you so much for help @AluanHaddad it's helps a lot

Comment: My pleasure, sir

Comment: Take a look at this bug I filed against the C# 7.0+ Roslyn tooling for Visual Studio as an example. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18371

Answer (score 1):

This means your DI container is trying to construct a StudentsController, and it cannot seem to find a registration for your UnitOfWork class (or any of its dependencies).

Make sure the UnitOfWork class (or better: the interface it implements) is registered in your DI of choice, along with all other referenced interfaces/classes.

EDIT:
After looking at your code, you're missing a registration for the AirlineContext. Furthermore, you're **new**ing stuff (the AirlineRepository in UnitOfWork) while you're using DI.

I can't help but get the feeling you haven't completely understood this yet...

Comment: thank you so much for quick replay @rick van den Bosch
& you are right i am newbie in .netcore and implementing code in design pattern UnitofWork and Repository Pattern. so i am stuck in this scenario.
One more thing can you help me where can i register my airlineContext Class Please?

Comment: For registering services, have a look at the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: if you see closely i already registered 
`services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        services.AddTransient<IAirlineRepository, AirlineRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();`

Comment: Nope, you didn't. The AirlineContext is _not_ in your list of registered services. Only the repository and the unit of work are.

Comment: When i doing Defaultconnection while i am creating of object.
One more thing before implementing UnitOfWork concept every things is working fine you can see in this example i am sharing link below:
https://github.com/MurtuzaTravadi/DotNetCoreRepositoryPattern

Can you please suggest how can implement in proper way please it will help me alot and save my time 

Thank you

Comment: Please see this code i am registering context
`public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddEntityFramework(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AirlineContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
    }`

Comment: @Murtuza, what Mr. Rick van den Bosch is saying is exactly what I was trying to say. He is correct. Also please format the code properly in your git issue or it is unlikely to be well received. Your code blocks are malformed: see [creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks). Also, your `@mentions` have failed because they _inside_ of code blocks! At any rate, `AddEntityFramework(...)` does not imply registering the specific `AirlineContext` dependency upon which your code dependency chain ultimately relies.

Comment: @AluanHaddad & Mr.Rick van den Bosch i have update my code blocks in github can you please look at it ones more hope you will understand--thank you

Comment: They still look awful because you did not add the \`\`\`c#(linebreak)(code) (linebreak)``` formatting a suggested -> no syntax highlighting. Also, use of whitespace matters. Copy code into an IDE, format it, paste it back in.

Comment: i am sorry @AluanHaddad i am not following you i did my best to readable this github issue.. are you still not getting it?

Comment: @Murtuza did you read [creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks) that I posted above? it explains all about language specific syntax highlighting. And to answer your question, no-it is still wrong.

Comment: Compare the code I posted in this issue https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18371 to yours.

Comment: I am sorry @AluanHaddad my focus is now getting right answer not formatting

Comment: @Murtuza that is all well and fine except, formatting your code incorrectly on stack overflow is rude, while formatting it incorrectly on GitHub is both rude and unprofessional. Please take time to learn a few basic things. I do not appreciate having to read code like that on my GitHub projects. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Will do that you can give me some sample i will look into that Thanks @AluanHaddad